# What is this character: [esc][comma][esc]?

Tags: front-end

What is the character obtained with they key sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> called?  On my front end it is not displayed, but there's something there messing up my input.  It's a bit annoying when I'm after a $\mu$ but hit the wrong key.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.  I'd just like to note that despite what the help says, \[InvisibleComma] does not play nice with ordinary commas.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. `{a, b, c}` is fine, `{a\[InvisibleComma] b\[InvisibleComma] c}` is fine, but `{a\[InvisibleComma] b, c}` isn't. Very peculiar...

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I'll delete my comments in a few.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's what's called an [`\[InvisibleComma]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/InvisibleComma.html). It's useful for those times where you don't want a comma to appear, but you still need it, e.g. `"a[[p\[InvisibleComma]q]]"` for a matrix entry.

[image: screenshot]

The third entry uses an `\[InvisibleComma]` in between the matrix indices.

Comment: ah. the man himself :)

Answer (score 9):

The next time you wonder what a symbol is you can at least partially answer it yourself by entering it in a string wrapped in `FullForm`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(this is just before pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> the second time).  You would get:

> ```
> "\[InvisibleComma]"
> ```

Which is surely helpful in some way.  You can also get the help page for the character by entering it directly into the help search box:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Or just enter the original input described (Esc,Esc), select the cell, and look at its underlying expression -- on Mac, Shift+Cmd+E.

Comment: @murray good suggestion, though I think the Box structure is a little confusing to a new user.